# Can I use a delta index with sphinx to update existing records?

Tags: sphinx

Could I add a boolean field to my database data called something like "updated" and if it is true (which it would be for updated or added records) reindex it in my delta index? The reason I ask is that I believe my index for updated records would be in my main and delta indexes.

Edit: Looks like I could do this if I had a killlist that used this boolean on my main index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and this is why index merging was created in order to merge the "delta" back to the main index.

As long as you have method to select the portion of data that need to be created to the "delta" index, it would be okay.

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#delta-updates